# I have this line of syntax that I need to replace the static date so that it just calculates on the Transaction Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(d , TransactionDate , '2018/05/09') BETWEEN  100 AND  600 
            THEN (TotalValue-TotalPaidtoDate) 
    end )AS [30DaysAmount]
```

Comment: If you replace the static date with the transaction date, you will end up with a NULL in that field every time. The DATEDIFF function calculates the difference between the two dates

Comment: Thanks, worked that one out.  No worries solved the problem, or at least got a work around, shall put a parameter into the report then user can enter date.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean today's date?  If so, use `getdate()`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, TransactionDate , GETDATE()) BETWEEN 100 AND 600 
         THEN (TotalValue - TotalPaidtoDate) 
    END) AS [30DaysAmount]
```

I'm not sure what the column name has to do with the 501 days during the period.

Comment: thanks, no it needs to be calculated from the Transaction Date.

Comment: From the Transaction Date to when? I think you maybe want WHEN CONVERT(DATE, TransactionDate) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN blah? i.e. just today, rather than the difference being some range?